# Fetching javascript array content after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, postback

I have an array that is dynamically filled from some server-side C#. When the page loads that C# builds the content for a JQuery function. If the user changes a control, the page triggers a postback and that c# refills the content of my array with the correct data. However, even though it changes the data according to Firebug, I only see the data from the original array contents.

for example: The page initially loads this

```
<script>
  function pageLoad() {
    var ary= new Array('original-1','original-2', 'original-3', 'original-4');
  }
</script>
```

On post back, it loads this (when I inspect it with firebug this is what is loaded on postback)

```
<script>
  function pageLoad() {
    var ary= new Array('updated-1','updated-2', 'updated-3', 'updated-4');
  }
</script>
```

Even though the new content is loaded, I still get the original data not the updated data.

My question is: How can I use the data that is given on postback?
I feel like there is an easy fix, I just can not wrap my brain around it.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your var ary=array() OUTSIDE the function so it has global visibility.

```
    <script>
   var ary= new Array('');
  function pageLoad() {
    ary= new Array('original-1','original-2', 'original-3', 'original-4');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: That does not seem to be working. Even with making the array global, it's like it's not seeing the new data at all.

Comment: Can you post the code that is doing the postback?  I presume you're doing this asynchronously

Comment: This is the code that sets the array as well as holds the new data on postback.


function pageLoad() {
     var urlArray =  new Array( <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phURLArray" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder> );  
    }

Comment: This code is used to bring an array of image urls for a product category page, and later on in the script we load them and add them to the dom. Everything is working until you use another control that changes the page size or changes the sort. In which case, when these controls are changed, a postback occurs and the Array is filled with the new updated data. However, this urlArray is not pulling the new urls. (I know the array is updated because inspecting it with firebug shows the updated version yet the script is pulling the old version)